# SAT and #SAT in Quantum

Tags: satisfiability, quantum-computing

Let us look at the two questions that are NP-complete for a classical computer:

1. Given an arbitrary Boolean expression, find an assignment of variables that evaluates the expression to $0$ (SAT).
2. Given an arbitrary Boolean expression, count the number of assignments that evaluates the expression to $0$ (#SAT).

We know that the Simon's algorithm or the Grover's search can effectively solve the first problem with square-root complexity with high probability. Is it the case for the second problem too, or a quantum computer still needs to perform the same number of queries as a classical computer does?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many satisfying assignments there are.  If there are $t$ satisfying assignments, then it takes approximately $O(\sqrt{Nt})$ time for a quantum algorithm to identify all of them, if we are given an oracle to recognize which assignments are satisfying.  This can be compared to $O(N)$ time for a classical algorithm to do the same task.  So if $t$ is small, a quantum algorithm is significantly better.

See [Quantum Counting](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9805082), Gilles Brassard, Peter Hoyer, Alain Tapp, ICALP 1998.

Comment: Is there any specific name to this algorithm?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer depends on the specific problem. If the problem has many solutions, then the quantum advantage diminishes.